# Directing through form

Tags: php, laravel

Im a beginner with laravel. Im following the laracasts tutorial and Im stuck at the part where you access another page with a form by:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'created']) }}
```

for example.
Now that leads me to the right url but it gives me 
**Whoops, looks like something went wrong.**

As soon as I type the link manually it works normally.

This is the code of the page where it directs to:

**controller:**

```
public function created()
{
    return 'hello';
}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('created', 'TestController@created');
```

**View:**

```
   @extends('layout')

    @section('content')

        <h1> Test </h1>

    @stop
```

This is the form of the 1st page:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
        <h1>Create New User</h1>
        {{ Form::open(['url' => 'created']) }}
        <div>
            {{ Form::label('email', 'E-mail:')}}
            {{ Form::text('email')}}
        </div>


        <div>
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:')}}
            {{ Form::password('password')}}
        </div>


        <div>
        {{ Form::submit('Create')}}
        </div>
        {{ Form::close()}}
@stop
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form open by default links to a post method so what you need is either a post route or a get method. Following should work:

```
   {{ Form::open(['url' => 'created']) }}
        // Insert your fields/codes here
    {{ Form::close() }}
//Change route method to post
Route::post('created', 'TestController@created');
```

Please read the documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html) for more details.